# How to Create a Schema in MySQL?

Tags: php, mysql

How to create a schema with existing tables. I have 100 tables then now I want to create a schema for this table can you tell the procedure how or any tools.

I am trying the TOAD but it shows the result in HTML format. I want the result in SQL.

How create a schema using PHP.

Comment: do you want to get `create` statements for all the tables of an existing database?

Comment: Your question has nothing to do with PHP ;)

Comment: Thanks Flavius.I am taking a backup the structure of tables am i call this one is schema?

Comment: Yes, "the schema of a database" is just the structure of the relations (tables), without the data.

Answer (score 1):

A single `show create table <tablename>` statement in mysql command line tool will suffice, if you want schema only and no data. The result will be a full create table ddl

Answer (score 0):

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/mysqldump.html#option_mysqldump_no-data

That is:

`mysqldump --no-data -u <username> -p --database <dbname> <further options> > <dbname>.sql`

from the command line, on the server (perhaps via ssh).

Answer (score 0):

Take Dump of all table so you get schema...refer this [Dump](http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/09/backup-and-restore-mysql-database-using-mysqldump/)

## mysqldump -u root -p[root_password] [database_name] > dumpfilename.sql

Comment: you do not have to be root. You just need a user that has read access to the DB you wanted to take backup of.

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump --user MYSQL_USER --password=MYSQL_PASSWORD --add-locks --flush-privileges \
--add-drop-table --complete-insert --extended-insert --single-transaction \
--database DB_TO_BACKUP > FILENAME_FOR_SQL_STATEMENTS
```

this will give a file full of SQL create and insert statements that can be used to recreate the DB. The back slashes "\" are continue to next line... you may want to ignore it and write the whole command in one line

Now, I am not sure if you wanted to the whole Db with data or just tables... you may want to use `--no-data` to get rid of insert SQL statements and just create and delete (and lock) statements, e.g.

```
mysqldump --user MYSQL_USER --password=MYSQL_PASSWORD --add-locks --flush-privileges \
--add-drop-table --no-data --single-transaction \
--database DB_TO_BACKUP > FILENAME_FOR_SQL_STATEMENTS
```

Comment: He does say "the schema", so he only wants ... the schema.

Answer (score 0):

*...can you tell the procedure how or any tools*

You can use 'Generate Schema Script' or 'Backup' GUI tool in [dbForge Studio for MySQL](http://www.devart.com/dbforge/mysql/studio/).

Limited Backup is available in free express version, the size of backup files is limited to 1MB, it is enough for 100 table schemas.

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql workbench, connect with existing database there and you can import and export the schema in sql formats